# Stored Procedures - How to return multiple values after an Insert

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a Mysql Stored Procedure that returns two values after inserting a record. I want it to return the auto-generated ID and the value of one column. How would I go about doing this? Here's what I got so far:

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists insert_car//
create procedure insert_car(make VARCHAR(20), color VARCHAR(20))
begin
 INSERT INTO table values (make,'2003', color);
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
end//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LAST_INSERT_ID() is a normal function, you can just

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), the_column FROM the_table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ugh, it was simple as that. :) Thanks!